# Can I change the "android" and ".gradle" folders to other directory instead of the root directory in my project?

Tags: ionic4, monorepo, capacitor

I am creating an Ionic 4 + Capacitor project in a Nwrl/Nx workspace.

The root folder off my Ionic project inside the nx workspace is `apps/app/myApp`. I added capacitor to the project using the commands `npx cap init` and `npx cap add android`.

After running these commands, the capacitor created the folders `android` and `.gradle` in the root directory of my workspace.

However, I would like these folders to be inside `apps/app/myApp` folder.

Is it possible?

I checked if there is any config parameter that I could put inside `capacitor.config.json` but I do not figured out anything.

Comment: I found [this topic](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1157#issuecomment-457858673) in github from capacitor team that shows how I can do this.

I summary, I can set the `rootDir` in `capacitor.config.json`

Comment: Converting your comment to an answer to your own question is not only allowed but encouraged here.